# At what level is GPU hardware acceleration broken?

Tags: wayland, gpu

I'm using Wayland/Sway/Devuan/Firefox on an iMX8M and I don't manage 1 FPS in the WebGL Aquarium (one fish).  CPU load alternates between high and low, which is odd if it is doing software rendering.

The (GPU-relevant) start of the Sway log is below.

- At what level is GPU acceleration not working?  (Kernel, Sway, Firefox.)
- Is this the cause: (vivante) `Failed to open DRM device 9`.
- What tools can I use to work out at what level GPU acceleration is broken?

`~# drm_info /dev/dri/card1` gives me:

```
drmModeGetResources: Operation not supported
```

but `~# drm_info /dev/dri/card0` gives:

```
Node: /dev/dri/card0
├───Driver: imx-dcss (i.MX8MQ Display Subsystem) version 1.0.0 (20190917)
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_STEREO_3D supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_UNIVERSAL_PLANES supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_ATOMIC supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_ASPECT_RATIO supported
│   ├───DRM_CLIENT_CAP_WRITEBACK_CONNECTORS supported
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_BUFFER = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_VBLANK_HIGH_CRTC = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_PREFERRED_DEPTH = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_DUMB_PREFER_SHADOW = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_PRIME = 3
│   ├───DRM_CAP_TIMESTAMP_MONOTONIC = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_ASYNC_PAGE_FLIP = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CURSOR_WIDTH = 64
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CURSOR_HEIGHT = 64
│   ├───DRM_CAP_ADDFB2_MODIFIERS = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_PAGE_FLIP_TARGET = 0
│   ├───DRM_CAP_CRTC_IN_VBLANK_EVENT = 1
│   ├───DRM_CAP_SYNCOBJ = 0
│   └───DRM_CAP_SYNCOBJ_TIMELINE = 0
├───Device: platform nxp,imx8mq-dcss
├───Framebuffer size
│   ├───Width: [1, 4096]
│   └───Height: [1, 4096]
├───Connectors
│   └───Connector 0
│       ├───Object ID: 48
│       ├───Type: HDMI-A
│       ├───Status: connected
│       ├───Physical size: 600x340 mm
│       ├───Subpixel: unknown
│       ├───Encoders: {0}
│       ├───Modes
│       │   ├───1920x1080@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1920x1080@50.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1920x1080@24.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1280x720@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 
│       │   ├───1280x720@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───1280x720@50.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───720x576@50.00 driver nhsync nvsync 4:3 
│       │   ├───720x576@50.00 driver nhsync nvsync 16:9 
│       │   ├───720x480@59.94 driver nhsync nvsync 
│       │   ├───720x480@59.94 driver nhsync nvsync 16:9 
│       │   └───720x480@59.94 driver nhsync nvsync 4:3 
│       └───Properties
│           ├───"EDID" (immutable): blob = 61
│           ├───"DPMS": enum {On, Standby, Suspend, Off} = On
│           ├───"link-status": enum {Good, Bad} = Good
│           ├───"non-desktop" (immutable): range [0, 1] = 0
│           ├───"TILE" (immutable): blob = 0
│           ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 35
│           ├───"HDR_OUTPUT_METADATA": blob = 0
│           ├───"Colorspace": enum {Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater} = Default
│           ├───"Content Protection": enum {Undesired, Desired, Enabled} = Undesired
│           └───"HDCP Content Type": enum {HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1} = HDCP Type0
├───Encoders
│   └───Encoder 0
│       ├───Object ID: 47
│       ├───Type: TMDS
│       ├───CRTCS: {0}
│       └───Clones: {0}
├───CRTCs
│   └───CRTC 0
│       ├───Object ID: 35
│       ├───Mode: 1920x1080@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│       └───Properties
│           ├───"ACTIVE" (atomic): range [0, 1] = 1
│           ├───"MODE_ID" (atomic): blob = 58
│           │   └───1920x1080@60.00 driver phsync pvsync 16:9 
│           ├───"OUT_FENCE_PTR" (atomic): range [0, UINT64_MAX] = 0
│           └───"VRR_ENABLED": range [0, 1] = 0
└───Planes
    ├───Plane 0
    │   ├───Object ID: 31
    │   ├───CRTCs: {0}
    │   ├───Formats:
    │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │   │   ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
    │   │   ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
    │   │   ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
    │   │   ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
    │   │   ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
    │   │   ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
    │   │   ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
    │   │   ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
    │   │   ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
    │   │   ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
    │   │   ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │   │   ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
    │   │   ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
    │   │   ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
    │   │   ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
    │   │   ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
    │   │   ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
    │   │   ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
    │   │   ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
    │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │   └───Properties
    │       ├───"type" (immutable): enum {Overlay, Primary, Cursor} = Primary
    │       ├───"FB_ID" (atomic): object framebuffer = 60
    │       │   ├───Object ID: 60
    │       │   ├───Size: 1920x1080
    │       │   ├───Pitch: 7680
    │       │   ├───Bits per pixel: 32
    │       │   └───Depth: 32
    │       ├───"IN_FENCE_FD" (atomic): srange [-1, INT32_MAX] = -1
    │       ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 35
    │       ├───"CRTC_X" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_Y" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_W" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 1920
    │       ├───"CRTC_H" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 1080
    │       ├───"SRC_X" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_Y" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_W" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 1920
    │       ├───"SRC_H" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 1080
    │       ├───"IN_FORMATS" (immutable): blob = 32
    │       │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_TILED (0x600000000000001)
    │       │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_SUPER_TILED (0x600000000000002)
    │       │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │   ├───Unknown (0x600000000000005)
    │       │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │   └───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_LINEAR (0x0)
    │       │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │       ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │       ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
    │       │       ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
    │       │       ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
    │       │       ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
    │       │       ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
    │       │       ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
    │       │       ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
    │       │       ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
    │       │       ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
    │       │       ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
    │       │       ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │       ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
    │       │       ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
    │       │       ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
    │       │       ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
    │       │       ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
    │       │       ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
    │       │       ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
    │       │       ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
    │       │       ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │       │       ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │       │       └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │       ├───"zpos" (immutable): range [2, 2] = 2
    │       ├───"rotation": bitmask {rotate-0, rotate-90, rotate-180, rotate-270, reflect-x, reflect-y} = (rotate-0 | rotate-90)
    │       └───"alpha": range [0, UINT16_MAX] = 65535
    ├───Plane 1
    │   ├───Object ID: 36
    │   ├───CRTCs: {0}
    │   ├───Formats:
    │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │   │   ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
    │   │   ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
    │   │   ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
    │   │   ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
    │   │   ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
    │   │   ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
    │   │   ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
    │   │   ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
    │   │   ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
    │   │   ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
    │   │   ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │   │   ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
    │   │   ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
    │   │   ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
    │   │   ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
    │   │   ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
    │   │   ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
    │   │   ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
    │   │   ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
    │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │   └───Properties
    │       ├───"type" (immutable): enum {Overlay, Primary, Cursor} = Overlay
    │       ├───"FB_ID" (atomic): object framebuffer = 0
    │       ├───"IN_FENCE_FD" (atomic): srange [-1, INT32_MAX] = -1
    │       ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_X" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_Y" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_W" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"CRTC_H" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_X" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_Y" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_W" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"SRC_H" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"IN_FORMATS" (immutable): blob = 37
    │       │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000001)
    │       │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │       │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │       │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │       │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000002)
    │       │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │       │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │       │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │       │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000003)
    │       │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │       │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │       │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │       │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_TILED (0x600000000000001)
    │       │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_SUPER_TILED (0x600000000000002)
    │       │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │   └───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_LINEAR (0x0)
    │       │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
    │       │       ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
    │       │       ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
    │       │       ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
    │       │       ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
    │       │       ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
    │       │       ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
    │       │       ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
    │       │       ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
    │       │       ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
    │       │       ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
    │       │       ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
    │       │       ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
    │       │       ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
    │       │       ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
    │       │       ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
    │       │       ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
    │       │       ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
    │       │       ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
    │       │       ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
    │       │       ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
    │       │       ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
    │       │       ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
    │       │       └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
    │       ├───"zpos" (immutable): range [1, 1] = 1
    │       ├───"rotation": bitmask {rotate-0, rotate-90, rotate-180, rotate-270, reflect-x, reflect-y} = (rotate-0 | rotate-90)
    │       ├───"dtrc_table_ofs": range [0, UINT64_MAX] = 0
    │       ├───"COLOR_ENCODING": enum {ITU-R BT.601 YCbCr, ITU-R BT.709 YCbCr, ITU-R BT.2020 YCbCr} = ITU-R BT.709 YCbCr
    │       └───"COLOR_RANGE": enum {YCbCr limited range, YCbCr full range} = YCbCr full range
    └───Plane 2
        ├───Object ID: 41
        ├───CRTCs: {0}
        ├───Formats:
        │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
        │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
        │   ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
        │   ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
        │   ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
        │   ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
        │   ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
        │   ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
        │   ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
        │   ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
        │   ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
        │   ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
        │   ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
        │   ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
        │   ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
        │   ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
        │   ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
        │   ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
        │   ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
        │   ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
        │   ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
        │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
        │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
        │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
        └───Properties
            ├───"type" (immutable): enum {Overlay, Primary, Cursor} = Overlay
            ├───"FB_ID" (atomic): object framebuffer = 0
            ├───"IN_FENCE_FD" (atomic): srange [-1, INT32_MAX] = -1
            ├───"CRTC_ID" (atomic): object CRTC = 0
            ├───"CRTC_X" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_Y" (atomic): srange [INT32_MIN, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_W" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"CRTC_H" (atomic): range [0, INT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_X" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_Y" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_W" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"SRC_H" (atomic): range [0, UINT32_MAX] = 0
            ├───"IN_FORMATS" (immutable): blob = 42
            │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000001)
            │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
            │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
            │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
            │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000002)
            │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
            │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
            │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
            │   ├───Unknown (0xf100000000000003)
            │   │   ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
            │   │   ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
            │   │   └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
            │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_TILED (0x600000000000001)
            │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
            │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
            │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
            │   ├───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_VIVANTE_SUPER_TILED (0x600000000000002)
            │   │   ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
            │   │   ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
            │   │   └───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
            │   └───DRM_FORMAT_MOD_LINEAR (0x0)
            │       ├───ARGB8888 (0x34325241)
            │       ├───XRGB8888 (0x34325258)
            │       ├───ABGR8888 (0x34324241)
            │       ├───XBGR8888 (0x34324258)
            │       ├───RGBA8888 (0x34324152)
            │       ├───RGBX8888 (0x34325852)
            │       ├───BGRA8888 (0x34324142)
            │       ├───BGRX8888 (0x34325842)
            │       ├───XRGB2101010 (0x30335258)
            │       ├───XBGR2101010 (0x30334258)
            │       ├───RGBX1010102 (0x30335852)
            │       ├───BGRX1010102 (0x30335842)
            │       ├───ARGB2101010 (0x30335241)
            │       ├───ABGR2101010 (0x30334241)
            │       ├───RGBA1010102 (0x30334152)
            │       ├───BGRA1010102 (0x30334142)
            │       ├───AYUV (0x56555941)
            │       ├───UYVY (0x59565955)
            │       ├───VYUY (0x59555956)
            │       ├───YUYV (0x56595559)
            │       ├───YVYU (0x55595659)
            │       ├───NV12 (0x3231564e)
            │       ├───NV21 (0x3132564e)
            │       └───Unknown (0x30324b52)
            ├───"zpos" (immutable): range [0, 0] = 0
            ├───"rotation": bitmask {rotate-0, rotate-90, rotate-180, rotate-270, reflect-x, reflect-y} = (rotate-0 | rotate-90)
            ├───"dtrc_table_ofs": range [0, UINT64_MAX] = 0
            ├───"COLOR_ENCODING": enum {ITU-R BT.601 YCbCr, ITU-R BT.709 YCbCr, ITU-R BT.2020 YCbCr} = ITU-R BT.709 YCbCr
            └───"COLOR_RANGE": enum {YCbCr limited range, YCbCr full range} = YCbCr full range
```

The "sway -d" log output is:

```
~$ cat /tmp/sway.log
00:00:00.000 [sway/main.c:326] Sway version v1.5
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] Linux orac 5.10.9 #18 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 31 16:03:22 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:169] Contents of /etc/os-release:
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] PRETTY_NAME="Devuan GNU/Linux 4 (chimaera)"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] NAME="Devuan GNU/Linux"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] VERSION_ID="4"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] VERSION="4 (chimaera)"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] VERSION_CODENAME="chimaera"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] ID=devuan
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] ID_LIKE=debian
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] HOME_URL="https://www.devuan.org/"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] SUPPORT_URL="https://devuan.org/os/community"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.devuan.org/"
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:169] Contents of /etc/debian_version:
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:153] 11.1
00:00:00.004 [sway/main.c:141] LD_LIBRARY_PATH=(null)
00:00:00.005 [sway/main.c:141] LD_PRELOAD=(null)
00:00:00.005 [sway/main.c:141] PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
00:00:00.005 [sway/main.c:141] SWAYSOCK=(null)
00:00:00.005 [sway/server.c:43] Preparing Wayland server initialization
00:00:00.016 [INFO] [backend/session/logind.c:822] Successfully loaded logind session
00:00:00.021 [INFO] [backend/backend.c:157] Found 2 GPUs
00:00:00.021 [INFO] [backend/drm/backend.c:138] Initializing DRM backend for /dev/dri/card1 (vivante)
00:00:00.021 [ERROR] [backend/drm/drm.c:51] DRM universal planes unsupported
00:00:00.022 [ERROR] [backend/backend.c:163] Failed to open DRM device 9
00:00:00.023 [INFO] [backend/drm/backend.c:138] Initializing DRM backend for /dev/dri/card0 (imx-dcss)
00:00:00.023 [DEBUG] [backend/drm/drm.c:70] Using atomic DRM interface
00:00:00.023 [INFO] [backend/drm/drm.c:255] Found 1 DRM CRTCs
00:00:00.023 [INFO] [backend/drm/drm.c:176] Found 3 DRM planes
00:00:00.768 [INFO] [render/egl.c:297] Using EGL 1.4
00:00:00.768 [INFO] [render/egl.c:298] Supported EGL client extensions: EGL_EXT_device_base EGL_EXT_device_enumeration EGL_EXT_device_query EGL_EXT_platform_base EGL_KHR_client_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_EXT_client_extensions EGL_KHR_debug EGL_EXT_platform_device EGL_EXT_platform_wayland EGL_KHR_platform_wayland EGL_EXT_platform_x11 EGL_KHR_platform_x11 EGL_MESA_platform_gbm EGL_KHR_platform_gbm EGL_MESA_platform_surfaceless
00:00:00.768 [INFO] [render/egl.c:299] Supported EGL display extensions: EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_EXT_buffer_age EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers EGL_KHR_cl_event2 EGL_KHR_config_attribs EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap EGL_KHR_no_config_context EGL_KHR_reusable_sync EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_MESA_configless_context EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export EGL_MESA_query_driver
00:00:00.768 [INFO] [render/egl.c:300] EGL vendor: Mesa Project
00:00:00.768 [DEBUG] [render/egl.c:175] Supported dmabuf buffer formats: AB4H XB4H AR30 XR30 AB30 XB30 AR24 AB24 XR24 XB24 AR15 RG16 R8   R16  GR88 GR32 YUV9 YU11 YU12 YU16 YU24 YVU9 YV11 YV12 YV16 YV24 NV12 P010 P012 P016 NV16 AYUV XYUV YUYV UYVY
00:00:00.792 [INFO] [render/gles2/renderer.c:693] Using OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.3.5
00:00:00.792 [INFO] [render/gles2/renderer.c:694] GL vendor: Mesa/X.org
00:00:00.792 [INFO] [render/gles2/renderer.c:695] GL renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1, 128 bits)
00:00:00.792 [INFO] [render/gles2/renderer.c:696] Supported GLES2 extensions: GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_conditional_render GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_APPLE_texture_max_level GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_read_format_bgra GL_EXT_frag_depth GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_OES_viewport_array GL_ANGLE_pack_reverse_row_order GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_EXT_occlusion_query_boolean GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_rg GL_EXT_unpack_subimage GL_NV_draw_buffers GL_NV_read_buffer GL_NV_read_depth GL_NV_read_depth_stencil GL_NV_read_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers GL_EXT_map_buffer_range GL_KHR_debug GL_KHR_robustness GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_NV_pixel_buffer_object GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_OES_surfaceless_context GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_shader_group_vote GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix GL_EXT_tessellation_point_size GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_base_instance GL_EXT_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_sub_texture GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_EXT_render_snorm GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_EXT_texture_cube_map_array GL_EXT_texture_norm16 GL_EXT_texture_view GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_context_flush_control GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior GL_NV_image_formats GL_OES_copy_image GL_OES_draw_buffers_indexed GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_OES_gpu_shader5 GL_OES_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_sample_variables GL_OES_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_OES_tessellation_point_size GL_OES_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_border_clamp GL_OES_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_cube_map_array GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_texture_view GL_EXT_blend_func_extended GL_EXT_buffer_storage GL_EXT_float_blend GL_EXT_geometry_point_size GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_KHR_no_error GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_geometry_point_size GL_OES_geometry_shader GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_EXT_clip_cull_distance GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc_srgb GL_MESA_shader_integer_functions GL_EXT_clip_control GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_texture_compression_bptc GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile GL_EXT_EGL_image_storage GL_EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch_non_coherent GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8 GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod GL_MESA_framebuffer_flip_y GL_EXT_depth_clamp GL_EXT_texture_query_lod
00:00:00.816 [sway/main.c:373] Starting sway version v1.5
00:00:00.816 [sway/server.c:56] Initializing Wayland server
00:00:00.816 [INFO] [render/gles2/renderer.c:477] EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display is not supported
00:00:00.816 [DEBUG] [types/wlr_idle.c:247] idle manager created
00:00:00.816 [INFO] [backend/noop/backend.c:51] Creating noop backend
00:00:00.816 [INFO] [backend/headless/backend.c:171] Creating headless backend
```

`~# eglinfo --help` provides:

```
EGL client extensions string:
    EGL_EXT_device_base EGL_EXT_device_enumeration EGL_EXT_device_query
    EGL_EXT_platform_base EGL_KHR_client_get_all_proc_addresses
    EGL_EXT_client_extensions EGL_KHR_debug EGL_EXT_platform_device
    EGL_EXT_platform_wayland EGL_KHR_platform_wayland
    EGL_EXT_platform_x11 EGL_KHR_platform_x11 EGL_MESA_platform_gbm
    EGL_KHR_platform_gbm EGL_MESA_platform_surfaceless

GBM platform:
EGL API version: 1.4
EGL vendor string: Mesa Project
EGL version string: 1.4
EGL client APIs: OpenGL OpenGL_ES 
EGL extensions string:
    EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_EXT_buffer_age
    EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import_modifiers
    EGL_KHR_cl_event2 EGL_KHR_config_attribs EGL_KHR_create_context
    EGL_KHR_create_context_no_error EGL_KHR_fence_sync
    EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace
    EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
    EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
    EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_KHR_image_pixmap
    EGL_KHR_no_config_context EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
    EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context EGL_EXT_pixel_format_float
    EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_MESA_configless_context
    EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export EGL_MESA_query_driver
Configurations:
     bf lv colorbuffer dp st  ms    vis   cav bi  renderable  supported
  id sz  l  r  g  b  a th cl ns b    id   eat nd gl es es2 vg surfaces 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
0x01 32  0 10 10 10  2  0  0  0 0 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x02 32  0 10 10 10  2 16  0  0 0 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x03 32  0 10 10 10  2 24  0  0 0 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x04 32  0 10 10 10  2 24  8  0 0 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x05 32  0 10 10 10  2 32  0  0 0 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x06 32  0 10 10 10  2  0  0  4 1 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x07 32  0 10 10 10  2 16  0  4 1 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x08 32  0 10 10 10  2 24  0  4 1 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x09 32  0 10 10 10  2 24  8  4 1 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x0a 32  0 10 10 10  2 32  0  4 1 0x30335241--         y  y  y     win
0x0b 30  0 10 10 10  0  0  0  0 0 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x0c 30  0 10 10 10  0 16  0  0 0 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x0d 30  0 10 10 10  0 24  0  0 0 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x0e 30  0 10 10 10  0 24  8  0 0 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x0f 30  0 10 10 10  0 32  0  0 0 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x10 30  0 10 10 10  0  0  0  4 1 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x11 30  0 10 10 10  0 16  0  4 1 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x12 30  0 10 10 10  0 24  0  4 1 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x13 30  0 10 10 10  0 24  8  4 1 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x14 30  0 10 10 10  0 32  0  4 1 0x30335258--         y  y  y     win
0x15 32  0  8  8  8  8  0  0  0 0 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x16 32  0  8  8  8  8 16  0  0 0 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x17 32  0  8  8  8  8 24  0  0 0 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x18 32  0  8  8  8  8 24  8  0 0 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x19 32  0  8  8  8  8 32  0  0 0 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1a 32  0  8  8  8  8  0  0  4 1 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1b 32  0  8  8  8  8 16  0  4 1 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1c 32  0  8  8  8  8 24  0  4 1 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1d 32  0  8  8  8  8 24  8  4 1 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1e 32  0  8  8  8  8 32  0  4 1 0x34325241--         y  y  y     win
0x1f 24  0  8  8  8  0  0  0  0 0 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x20 24  0  8  8  8  0 16  0  0 0 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x21 24  0  8  8  8  0 24  0  0 0 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x22 24  0  8  8  8  0 24  8  0 0 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x23 24  0  8  8  8  0 32  0  0 0 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x24 24  0  8  8  8  0  0  0  4 1 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x25 24  0  8  8  8  0 16  0  4 1 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x26 24  0  8  8  8  0 24  0  4 1 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x27 24  0  8  8  8  0 24  8  4 1 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x28 24  0  8  8  8  0 32  0  4 1 0x34325258--         y  y  y     win
0x29 16  0  5  6  5  0  0  0  0 0 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2a 16  0  5  6  5  0 16  0  0 0 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2b 16  0  5  6  5  0 24  0  0 0 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2c 16  0  5  6  5  0 24  8  0 0 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2d 16  0  5  6  5  0 32  0  0 0 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2e 16  0  5  6  5  0  0  0  4 1 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x2f 16  0  5  6  5  0 16  0  4 1 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x30 16  0  5  6  5  0 24  0  4 1 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x31 16  0  5  6  5  0 24  8  4 1 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win
0x32 16  0  5  6  5  0 32  0  4 1 0x36314752--         y  y  y     win

Wayland platform:
eglinfo: eglInitialize failed

X11 platform:
eglinfo: eglInitialize failed

Device platform:
eglinfo: eglInitialize failed
```